# Excel: Summation formula, from a value in a cell, to a value in another cell

Tags: excel, sum

I have the following [summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation):

[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/674/QKWX9O.png]

In text:

> SUM (k*1.07^n), n=c1 to n=c2

`k`, `c1` and `c2` are 3 single numbers, specified in respective individual cells.

`k` is a constant, but `c1` and `c2` should be dynamically changeable.

**Is that possible to do in Excel, and if so, how?**

---

I know it's a fairly simple mathematical concept so I'd be surprised if Excel couldn't do it, but I haven't been able to find the formula myself. I've tried `SUM` and `SUMIF`, but from what I understand, that requires me to fill a whole range of cells each time I want to calculate something. I've also found some suggestions to use arrays in Excel, which I understand is automatically filling cells - which is at least a little more automated - but I'd rather not fill extra cells, if it's possible.

As a sidenote, I read Excel's accuracy is bad in high digit numbers, but as long as the first 5 digits are correct, it'll be accurate enough for my purpose.

Comment: Do you need a continuous or discrete result?

Comment: @jbarker2160 I'm not familiar with those concepts. I'm guessing it's a discrete result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *k*, *c<sub>1</sub>*, and *c<sub>2</sub>* in A1, B1 and C1 respectively, use the following formula:

```
=A1*SUMPRODUCT(1.07^ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&C1)))
```

Regards